# List of average genre tempo (BPM) levels?

Tags: tempo, genre

I've been told before that a genre such as drum and bass averages a BPM of 160-180, whereas dubstep is around 140 BPM and hip-hop is around 115 BPM.

Does anyone know where I can get a list of popular genres with their average BPM?

Comment: I think the [BPM Database](http://www.bpmdatabase.com/) could help you, but you'll have to carry out the computation of the average yourself by retrieving all songs under a given genre.

Comment: the stupid protection status of this question doesn't allow me to post this as an answer (if I don't lose a week or something pretending to bother about other people's ignorance) but  [here's a very good list of tempos: classical, jazz, and organized by dance genre](http://www2.siba.fi/muste1/index.php?id=102&la=en).
It also specifies a catch with songs that tend to be written "alla breve".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let's start a list!

- Hip Hop is around 80-115 BPM
- Triphop / Downtempo around 90-110 BPM
- Concert marches are typically ~120 BPM.
- House varies between 118 and 135 BPM

  - UK garage/2-step is usually between 130-135 BPM
  - UK funky is around 130 BPM
- Techno 120-160 BPM

  - Generally around 120-135
  - Acid Techno 135-150
  - Schranz around 150
- Dubstep is around <del>140 BPM</del> 70's to 100 (mostly 80-90)

  - *Dubstep is not 140 BPM. I don't know why that number gets thrown around, but most dubstep is from the 70's to 100, with most falling in-between 80 and 90. In many songs it's often for a double-time break to happen, at which point it will reach 140~200, respectively, but it shouldn't be timed that way.* – [n_b](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/33439/n-b)
  - *Dubstep is 70 - 75 BPM, which is equivalent to 140 - 150 BPM depending on if you count the snare on the 2 and 4 or the 3 of the measure.
- Screamers are usually 130-150 BPM
- Hardstyle is around 150 BPM
- Juke/Footwork is around 160 BPM
- Drum and Bass averages a BPM of 160-180

  - Oldschool jungle is around 160-170
  - Drum & Bass and Drumstep and Neurofunk 170-180
- Grime 140 BPM

Some of the basic tempo markings

- Largo is 40-60 BPM
- Larghetto is 60-66 BPM
- Adagio is 66-76 BPM
- Andante is 76-108 BPM
- Moderato is 108-120 BPM
- Allegro is 120-168 BPM
- Presto is 168-200 BPM
- Prestissimo is 200+ BPM

See the discussion on [the terms Lento and Agitato as they relate to tempo](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/what-tempo-is-agitato).

Comment: Good list, but the ones from "Largo" and down are tempo notations itself, although a lot of composers have used the notations as part of the piece name.

Comment: Also, take a look at [Wikipedia article about Tempo (markings)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo#Italian_tempo_markings) and [BPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo#Beats_per_minute). Some genre like [Speedcore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedcore) can achieve extreme tempo above 300 BPM.

Comment: Dubstep is produced with DAWs at 140BPM, But If you see how the Rhythm goes Musically it's actually 70BPM

Answer (score 6):

Classical music averages around 120-140 BPM.

When you consider the tempos there's an even broader range.

- < 30     Grave
- 40-50    Largo
- 51-60    Larghetto
- 61-76    Adagio (usually around 72)
- 77-83    Andantino (slower than andante)
- 84-90    Andante
- 90-100   Andante Moderato
- 100-115  Moderato
- 116 Allegro Moderato
- 117-119 Allegretto
- 120-160 Allegro
- 130 (around) Allegro con Brio
- 140-160 Molto Allegro
- 161-170 Allegro Vivace
- 171-179 Vivace
- 180-199 Presto
- 200 (and above) Prestissimo